# How to upload file using ajax

Tags: ajax, file, upload

I was trying to send a single file to the server without having to change the webpage. I decided to use this plugin: http://cmlenz.github.com/jquery-iframe-transport/ 
I am very confused on how to proceed for an upload without changing the webpage...
the uploadimg.php returns:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: photo in <b>C:\website\uploadimg.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: photo in <b>C:\website\uploadimg.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<img src="userimg/" />
```

My files:

postAd.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#photo1').on('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "uploadimg.php",
            files: $("#photo1:file"),
            iframe: true,
            processData: false
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' name='photo' id='photo1' /></br>
</body>
</html>
```

uploadimg.php

```
<?php 
$file_tmp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][0];
$file = $_FILES['photo']['name'][0];
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "userimg/$file");
echo '<img src="userimg/' .$file .'" />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not submitting a form, so the 'photo' field is not going to be sent with the AJAX call. If you have a debugger available, check the $_FILES array to see what got populated. From [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), it appears that you might be looking for a 'userfile' index, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
function upload(event) {

var formData = new FormData($('#uploadForm')[0]);

$.ajax( {             
    url     : "upload.do",
    type        : "POST",
    data    : formData,
    cache   : false,
    contentType     : false,
    processData : false,

});

@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadCsr", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String uploadCsr(@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response) {
// read the file using inputstream

}
```

Answer (score -1):

after a lot of searching I found this simple easy file uploading using ajax.
you can find it at [upload in php without refreshing](http://tuts.wtfdiary.com/2012/06/file-upload-in-php-without-refreshing.html)