# Get contents form HttpRequest

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I am uploading a .war file in jsp as follows,

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" size="50">
```

example: C:\1234\OnlineBookStore.war

and uploading the form using ajax as follows,

```
var fileValue = document.getElementById("file1").value; 
url=url+"&fileName="+fileValue;
loadPage('downloaddiv', url);
```

when i get the filename in java i am just getting the name of the file(OnlineBookStore.war

) without its contents,

```
File uploadedFile = new File(request.getParameter("fileName"));
```

how to get the file with contents form request?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251758/how-to-upload-file-using-ajax

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the File API if you want to read the data from files to upload via XMLHttpRequest.

There is a guide to [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) on MDN.

Note that this requires a browser that supports this bleeding edge feature.

The classic way to upload files via Ajax is to submit a form to a hidden iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should checkout this question: [How to get the file path from HTML input form in Firefox 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3)

There is little to no reason why server should have to know full file path. If you want to upload a file, you'll need to use an appropriate library like [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) and transfer the file using.

```
<form action="upload-script-url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Apache Commons FileUpload will then accept and transform encoded file into a usable form.

Otherwise you'll need to use JavaScript to get that path.